# Notifications and Syncing Exchange/Office-365 Calendars

Tags: calendar, outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm working on an application (server-side) that requires syncing calendar events.

The application is intended to work with both Google Calendar and Microsoft Exchange calendar services. I already have the Google calendar syncing in place [thanks to their use of web-hook notifications when a resource changes](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push), but I'm having trouble figuring out what method to use with Microsoft's service.

All I've been able to find when searching for a Microsoft solution [has been related to EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx). Does the [Office 365 calendar API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations) provide any sort of notification mechanism? Am I missing some link/relation between O365 and EWS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are working on offering webhooks and sync for Office 365 Mail, Calendar and Contact REST APIs, especially for Calendar.  Stay tuned.

[UPDATE] You can use Exchange Web Services in the interim.  Take a look at [SyncFolderItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/aa563967(v=exchg.150).aspx), [SyncFolderHierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/aa564829(v=exchg.150).aspx), and [Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).  In the Notifications doc, you need to look at the info for Push Notifications.

Comment: Oh, so they're not yet available? Ok, well at least I know they're coming, haha. In the absence of those features, would there be another optimal option/solution? Would it involve EWS?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using O365, you will likely want Streaming Notifications as opposed to Push Notifications.

Comment: Through EWS? I don't see any O365-specific documentation regarding notifications. I only see the EWS docs for it.

Comment: Yes, EWS Managed API.  EWS is designed to present the same API to you whether you do O365 or on-prem Exchange.